How to run non-headless-chromedriver from SSH?
I've been trying to run Chromedriver through Selenium (Python) on my Raspberry Pi, but it doesn't work when I start my script from SSH (there is no helpful errors, just a timeout, hence no Stacktrace).
However, if I actually login into the machine, with a VNC viewer, and run the same exact screen, it works perfectly.
I suspect it's because when I execute the script from my remote machine through SSH there is no video output, so it hangs. How do I fix this?

I'm running into the same issues here. The (Python) Selenium script works fine through an SSH connection. Even if this connection is closed and it's run by a crontab. But if the system starts and runs the script, without ever having an SSH connection, the webdriver exits with code 1. I thought it was related to /home/ubuntu being encrypted but I ruled that out now

You can fix this by executing this before your command:
export DISPLAY=:0.0
It sets an environment variable tells your SSH session that you want to target the X server on the host.
